# Remove /Strip unwanted function (preg_replace)

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, strip

For example, we have some text like this:

```
    // comments
    someFunc.f.log({
      obj:obj,
      other:other
    });
    console.log('here');
    someFunc.f.log({
      obj:obj,
      other:other
    }
);
    console.log('here');
    // comments
```

I want from this text strip someFunc.f.log(); function in PHP backend and in output get:

```
// comments
console.log('here');
console.log('here');
// comments
```

How we can reach this point?

Comment: Are there nested parentheses? Else you can try [something like this](https://eval.in/520985).

Comment: Thaaanks!!! At this time is not. But maybe you can provide solution and for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no nested parentheses, you can try with [this regex <sup>regex101</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/mO1yO3/4)

```
$str = preg_replace('/^\h*someFunc\.f\.log\([^)]*\);\R*|^\h+/m', "", $str);
```

[like this demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/520993). If there's nested parentheses, try with [that recursive regex <sup>regex101</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/oO3nB3/3)

```
'/^\h*someFunc\.f\.log(\((?>[^)(]*(?1)?)*\));\R*|^\h+/m'
```

[like another demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/520990)

- `^` matches start of line with `m` multiline [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)
- `|` is the pipe symbol for alternation
- `\h` matches a horizontal space
- `[^`... opens a negated character class
- `(?1)` pastes first parenthesized [subpattern](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php)
- `\R` matches any newline sequence

(more explanation and a code generator is available at regex101)

Comment: You're welcome! Make semicolon optional if needed `;?`